# Safari 5 changes on use of javascript bookmarklets?

Tags: javascript, safari, bookmarklet, safari-extension

Is there now a length limit or other changes to how Safari 5 uses javascript bookmarklets as links in Bookmarks or the bookmark bar?

The bookmarklet below works in Safari 4, but in Safari 5 I get the error "Safari can't use Javascript for this action." It doesn't seem to have anything to do with opening a new window, as the second script below works in 5 and opens a new window.

Are there other ways to use javascript for browser actions, either as bookmarklets or Safari extensions?

**Update 10/07/11:**

Bookmarklet now works in Safari 5 (but not 4) with one change, changing the `100% to 100%25`:

```
javascript:s=document.getElementsByTagName('STYLE'); ex=document.getElementsByTagName('LINK'); d=window.open().document; /*set base href*/d.open();d.close(); b=d.body; function trim(s){return s.replace(/^\s*\n/, '').replace(/\s*$/, ''); }; function iff(a,b,c){return b?a+b+c:'';}function add(h){b.appendChild(h);} function makeTag(t){return d.createElement(t);} function makeText(tag,text){t=makeTag(tag);t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(text)); return t;} add(makeText('style', 'iframe{width:100%25;height:18em;border:1px solid;')); add(makeText('h3', d.title='Style sheets in ' + location.href)); for(i=0; i%3Cs.length; ++i) { add(makeText('h4','Inline style sheet'  + iff(' title="',s[i].title,'"'))); add(makeText('pre', trim(s[i].innerHTML))); } for (i=0; i%3Cex.length; ++i) { rs=ex[i].rel.split(' '); for(j=0;j%3Crs.length;++j) if (rs[j].toLowerCase()=='stylesheet') { add(makeText('h4','link rel="' + ex[i].rel + '" href="' + ex[i].href + '"' + iff(' title="',ex[i].title,'"'))); iframe=makeTag('iframe'); iframe.src=ex[i].href; add(iframe); break; } } void 0
```

Bookmarklet that fails in Safari 5 but works in 4:

```
javascript:s=document.getElementsByTagName('STYLE'); ex=document.getElementsByTagName('LINK'); d=window.open().document; /*set base href*/d.open();d.close(); b=d.body; function trim(s){return s.replace(/^\s*\n/, '').replace(/\s*$/, ''); }; function iff(a,b,c){return b?a+b+c:'';}function add(h){b.appendChild(h);} function makeTag(t){return d.createElement(t);} function makeText(tag,text){t=makeTag(tag);t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(text)); return t;} add(makeText('style', 'iframe{width:100%;height:18em;border:1px solid;')); add(makeText('h3', d.title='Style sheets in ' + location.href)); for(i=0; i%3Cs.length; ++i) { add(makeText('h4','Inline style sheet'  + iff(' title="',s[i].title,'"'))); add(makeText('pre', trim(s[i].innerHTML))); } for (i=0; i%3Cex.length; ++i) { rs=ex[i].rel.split(' '); for(j=0;j%3Crs.length;++j) if (rs[j].toLowerCase()=='stylesheet') { add(makeText('h4','link rel="' + ex[i].rel + '" href="' + ex[i].href + '"' + iff(' title="',ex[i].title,'"'))); iframe=makeTag('iframe'); iframe.src=ex[i].href; add(iframe); break; } } void 0
```

Bookmarklet that works with a new window:

```
javascript:var MTl=document.getElementsByTagName('script');for(var MTi=0,MTr,MTa=[];MTl[MTi];MTi++){if(MTr=MTl[MTi].getAttribute('src')){MTa[MTa.length]=MTl[MTi];}}if(!MTa.length){alert('This page does not use any external scripts');}else if(MTa.length==1){void(window.open(MTa[0].getAttribute('src')));}else{var MTw=window.open('');MTw.document.open();MTw.document.write('<html><head><title>External scripts for '+document.title+'<\/title><\/head><body><h1>External scripts for '+document.title+'<\/h1><p>');for(MTi=0;MTa[MTi];MTi++){MTw.document.write('<a href=\''+MTa[MTi].getAttribute('src')+'\'>'+(MTa[MTi].id?MTa[MTi].id:MTa[MTi].getAttribute('src').replace(/\/$/,'').replace(/^.*\//,''))+'<\/a><br>');}MTw.document.write('<\/p><\/body><\/html>');MTw.document.close();}
```

Comment: This might be better implemented as a Safari Extension - and yes, Stack Overflow would probably be a better place for your question.

Comment: I think Safari 5 doesn't like it when a bookmarklet tries to open a window.

Comment: I have other bookmarklets - one added above - that open a new window in Safari 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the same error from one of my bookmarklets.  It turned out that it was improperly URL-encoded all along, and Safari 5.1 must just be more strict about that than previous versions.  It looks like you have the same problem.  Replace literal '%' characters with '%25' and see if you have better luck. (For example, change "`width:100%;`" to "`width:100%25;`".)

Too bad there's such a cryptic error message.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, changing the one instance of % to %25. Never would have figured that out myself.

Comment: Been searching for ages for an answer to this.  Thank you!